# Ubuntu 18, Install azure-cli 2.0.81

Tags: python, pip, azure-cli

I am trying to install azure cli old version I got fresh ubuntu 18 or 20 i tried both.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
pip install azure-cli==2.0.81
```

Its not working. I tried multiple OS with 18,20 ubuntu.

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/tmp/pip-build-UhSu0K/antlr4-python2-runtime/setup.py", line 13
description=f'ANTLR {v} runtime for Python 2.7.12'
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-UhSu0K/antlr4-python2-runtime/

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Try with Python 3.6+

Comment: Python3 is  Python 3.6.9 (default, Mar 15 2022, 13:55:28)  and python is Python 2.7.17 (default, Jul  1 2022, 15:56:32)

Comment: After installing Python 3.7.5  I ran same issue

Comment: You might have multiple pythons. Try with ‘python3 -m pip install …” (and replace python3 with whichever Python you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solution Worked, I am using python 3.7.5 and it works.

python3 -m pip install "package"

THank you,

Comment: Seems like you do have multiple pythons installed. So from now own, prefer using “python -m pip” instead of the naked “pip”. And of course replace python with whichever interpreter you are using.